# Verilog Testbench Results not showing desired dataRead?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I have created the following module for Data_Mem:

```
module Data_Mem(
    input clk,
    input memWrite,
    input [5:0] addr,
    input [31:0] writeData,
    output [31:0] readData
    );
    reg [31:0] readData;
    reg [31:0] addrSpace [0:63];
    integer i;
    
    initial begin
       for (i=0;i<64;i=i+1)
           addrSpace[i] = 0;
    end
    always @ (*) begin
       if (memWrite == 1)
           begin
           addrSpace[addr] <= writeData;
           end
       readData <= addrSpace[addr];
    end
 endmodule
```

Now, I have written the following testbench to see if I can get values to stay in a specified location or address. The testbench is as follows:

```
    reg [5:0] addr;
    reg [31:0] writeData;
    reg memWrite, clk;
    wire [31:0] readData;
    //
    Data_Mem datamem_testUnit1(.clk(clk), .memWrite(memWrite), .writeData(writeData), .readData(readData));
    initial
        begin
            #10 a = 6'b001111; writeData = 32'h000A; memWrite = 0;
            #10 a = 6'b000001; writeData = 32'h000C; memWrite = 1;
            #10 a = 6'b000001; 
            #10 $finish;
            end
      endmodule
```

For the simulation results, I see that its taking in my desired values just fine, but dataRead is just XXXX for the whole time. I have included a second addr 00011 as to see whether this result is because of any sort of overlap while writing, but I do not see the desired "000C" for readData even when the addr is still declared as 000001. Please help!
[I have included a screenshot of my simulation results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EVwz.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply forgot to connect the `addr` signal in your testbench to the `addr` port of your Data_Mem module. Try

```
    Data_Mem datamem_testUnit1(.clk(clk), .memWrite(memWrite), .addr(addr), .writeData(writeData), .readData(readData));
```

Also, your always-block will infer latches. I think you probably want it to be clocked, like this:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
```

This involves having to drive the clk port in your testbench, however.